# gdb - Find the password

Tags: gdb

Let's say I have the following functions:

```
void personalData()
{
    char password[30];
    puts("Please enter your password");
    fgets(password, 6, stdin);

    if(correctPassword(password) != 0) {
        puts("Try again later !");
    }
    else {
        puts("Hello master");
    }
}

int correctPassword(char password[5])
{
    int i = 0;
    char desiredPassword[5] = {0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15, 0x16};
    char hash[5] = {0x22, 0x23, 0x24, 0x25, 0x26};

    for(i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        password[i] ^= hash[i];
    }
    return strncmp(password, desiredPassword, 5);
}

int main() {
    personalData();
    return 0;
}
```

My goal is to use **gdb** to find what password I should choose for `password` in order for the function personalData to print **Hello master**. I tried using breakpoints, many dissemble for every portion but I have no clue where to look for the actual result. I also tried to look in strncmp but with no result.
*I am not supposed to change the source code.*

Comment: Your code is *incomplete* -- where does `hash` come from?

Comment: @EmployedRussian sorry, I forgot to copy that piece of code. Now it's done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My goal is to use gdb to find what password I should choose for password in order for the function personalData to print Hello master.

You didn't state the platform you are using. Let's assume Linux/x86_64. The platform is important because calling conventions depend on the platform. The answer here can be easily adjusted for a different platform.

Let's consider the (usually harder) case of optimized binary. Disassembly of `personalData` shows:

```
   0x000000000040074d <+45>:    callq  0x400560 <fgets@plt>
   0x0000000000400752 <+50>:    xor    %eax,%eax
   0x0000000000400754 <+52>:    mov    %rsp,%rdi
   0x0000000000400757 <+55>:    callq  0x400680 <correctPassword>
   0x000000000040075c <+60>:    test   %eax,%eax
   0x000000000040075e <+62>:    jne    0x400780 <personalData+96>
```

This tells us that after reading the password from `stdin`, we call `correctPassword` and change control depending on whether `correctPassword` returned 0 or non-zero. The next two instructions:

```
   0x0000000000400760 <+64>:    mov    $0x400851,%edi
   0x0000000000400765 <+69>:    callq  0x400530 <puts@plt>
```

are printing some output. What is being printed if `correctPassword` returned `0` and the jump was not taken?

```
(gdb) x/s 0x400851
0x400851:   "Hello master"
```

So our goal is to make `correctPassword` return 0. Let's look at its disassembly:

```
(gdb) disas correctPassword
....
  0x0000000000400673 <+99>: callq  0x4004c0 <strncmp@plt>
  0x0000000000400678 <+104>:    add    $0x28,%rsp
  0x000000000040067c <+108>:    retq
```

This tells us that the `correctPassword` returns whatever `strncmp` returned, i.e. returns our desired 0 *IFF* our password matches the first `N` characters of whatever it's being `strncmp`-ared with. Time to set a breakpoint on `strncmp`:

```
(gdb) break strncmp
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4004c0
(gdb) run
Starting program: /tmp/a.out
Please enter your password
aaaaaaaaa
```

Above I entered 9-character password, just as an initial guess.

```
Breakpoint 1, __strncmp_ssse3 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/../strcmp.S:174
174 ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/../strcmp.S: No such file or directory.
```

I happen to have GLIBC debug symbols installed, and could actually examine GLIBC source and source-level parameters, but you may not have that luxury, so I'll use the `Linux/x86_64` [calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#System_V_AMD64_ABI) instead. From it, you can see that the 3 parameters to `strncmp` are passed in `RDI`, `RSI` and `RDX` registers. What are their values?

```
(gdb) p/x $rdi
$1 = 0x7fffffffdd50
(gdb) p/x $rsi
$2 = 0x7fffffffdd20
(gdb) p/x $rdx
$3 = 0x5
```

Ok, so only the first 5 characters of the password are being compared, and any characters after that are ignored.

What are the strings being compared?

```
(gdb) x/s $rdi
0x7fffffffdd50: "CBEDG"
(gdb) x/s $rsi
0x7fffffffdd20: "\022\023\024\025\026"
```

Hmm, neither string looks like our "aaa..." password. Let's try a different password:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /tmp/a.out
Please enter your password
bbbbb

Breakpoint 1, __strncmp_ssse3 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/../strcmp.S:174
174 ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/../strcmp.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) x/s $rdi
0x7fffffffdd50: "@AFGD"
(gdb) x/s $rsi
0x7fffffffdd20: "\022\023\024\025\026"
```

We can now immediately see that the `$rsi` sequence did not change, and can assume that `"\022\023\024\025\026"` is the expected password.

We also see that the first `a` was transformed into `C`, and `b` into `@`. From here we can go one of two ways: we can try more characters and guess what the input -> obfuscated password algorithm is, or we can look at the disassembly some more and simply "read" it.

The disassembly shows:

```
   0x0000000000400622 <+18>:    movb   $0x12,(%rsp)
...
   0x000000000040062a <+26>:    movb   $0x13,0x1(%rsp)
   0x000000000040062f <+31>:    movb   $0x14,0x2(%rsp)
   0x0000000000400634 <+36>:    movb   $0x15,0x3(%rsp)
   0x0000000000400639 <+41>:    movb   $0x16,0x4(%rsp)
   0x000000000040063e <+46>:    movb   $0x22,0x10(%rsp)
   0x0000000000400643 <+51>:    movb   $0x23,0x11(%rsp)
   0x0000000000400648 <+56>:    movb   $0x24,0x12(%rsp)
   0x000000000040064d <+61>:    movb   $0x25,0x13(%rsp)
   0x0000000000400652 <+66>:    movb   $0x26,0x14(%rsp)
```

Since we know that the "target" string is `\022\023...`, it's a fair guess that instructions from `0x4006322` through `0x400639` simply initialize the target string (note that `0x12` == `\022`). Perhaps instructions starting from `0x40063e` have to do with obfuscation? Looking further at disassembly, we see:

```
   0x0000000000400626 <+22>:    cmp    $0x5,%rax
...
   0x0000000000400657 <+71>:    je     0x40066b <correctPassword+91>
   0x0000000000400659 <+73>:    movzbl 0x10(%rsp,%rax,1),%edx
   0x000000000040065e <+78>:    xor    %dl,(%rdi,%rax,1)
   0x0000000000400661 <+81>:    add    $0x1,%rax
   0x0000000000400665 <+85>:    cmp    $0x5,%rax
   0x0000000000400669 <+89>:    jne    0x400659 <correctPassword+73>
```

This is a loop with a fixed trip count of 5, and in the loop we load a single character from one buffer and `XOR` that value with a character from another buffer. What are the chances that the first character of password is being `XOR`ed with `0x22`?

```
(gdb) p/c 'a' ^ 0x22
$5 = 67 'C'
(gdb) p/o 0x12
$6 = 022
(gdb) p/c 'b' ^ 0x22
$7 = 64 '@'
```

That looks promising! (You could of course confirm the contents of various buffers before and while the obfuscation process by setting breakpoints on appropriate instructions).

As a final confirmation of our guess, the last character is being `XOR`ed with `0x26`.

```
(gdb) p/c 'a' ^ 0x26
$8 = 71 'G'           # matches last char of 'aaa...' guess
(gdb) p/c 'b' ^ 0x26
$9 = 68 'D'           # matches last char of 'bbb...' guess
```

Finally, to construct the correct password, we need to take the "target" string and do the same sequence of `XOR`s on it:

```
(gdb) p/c 022 ^ 0x22
$10 = 48 '0'
(gdb) p/c 023 ^ 0x23
$11 = 48 '0'
... etc.
```

Therefore, the correct password is `00000`. Let's see if that works:

```
(gdb) disable
(gdb) run
Starting program: /tmp/a.out
Please enter your password
00000
Hello master
[Inferior 1 (process 45643) exited normally]
```

QED.

Answer (score 0):

As hash array could be not known (but accesible from GDB), you need to set password to `hash[n] ^ desiredPassword[n]`. As the inverse function of xor is xor, the result should be the desiredPassword.

Here is the demo code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>

char hash[] =  {0x23, 0x45, 0x55, 0xbb, 0xdd};    /* Some unknown values */


void personalData()
{
    char password[30];

    puts("Please enter your password");
    fgets(password, 6, stdin);


    if(correctPassword(password) != 0) {
        puts("Try again later !");
    }
    else {
        puts("Hello master");
    }
}

int correctPassword(char password[5])
{
    int i = 0;
    char desiredPassword[5] = {0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15, 0x16};
    for(i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        password[i] ^= hash[i];
    }
    return strncmp(password, desiredPassword, 5);
}


int main()
{
    personalData();
}
```

In std console:

```
gcc -g find_passwd.c
gdb .\a.exe -q
```

Once in gdb console:

```
(gdb) b correctPassword 
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4006b9: file find_passwd.c, line 32.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/xxx/workspace/c/xx/a.out 
Please enter your password
garbagePasswd

Breakpoint 1, correctPassword
32      int i = 0;
(gdb) n
33      char desiredPassword[5] = {0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15, 0x16};
(gdb) 
34      for(i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
(gdb) set password[0] = hash[0] ^ desiredPassword[0]
(gdb) set password[1] = hash[1] ^ desiredPassword[1]
(gdb) set password[2] = hash[2] ^ desiredPassword[2]
(gdb) set password[3] = hash[3] ^ desiredPassword[3]
(gdb) set password[4] = hash[4] ^ desiredPassword[4]
(gdb) c
Continuing.
Hello master
[Inferior 1 (process 19557) exited normally]
```

Comment: thanks, but I was supposed to do this using gdb... this way of solving has nothing to do with gdb.

Comment: I don't want to override anything... I want to find the **actual** value of the password using _gdb_

Comment: You just need to print the value for password after the `xor`

Comment: Something like this shall work `(gdb)p/s *password@5` which happens to be `0000`